# Terminating all sub-processes after an event

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue, multiprocessing, terminate

I have a Python multiprocessing scenario which I have simplified for my question here. There are x number of jobs to be processed in 2 parts. In my code, the 2 job parts are actually HTTP requests where part 2 is dependent on the results of part 1. Finally, there is a 3rd part that simply reports on how long parts 1 and 2 took and calculates a running average of time taken across all jobs.

Taking advantage of multiprocessing, I set up 2x process workers for Job Part 1 and also 2x workers for Job Part 2 and only 1x Reporter worker. To communicate the time taken for each job part, I am using Queues.

The code I have works fine for a complete workthrough of the specified x number of jobs BUT, I would like to add a timeout/cancel event that should stop all the workers and terminates gracefully.

In my code, I use the Report Worker to check for this event and when it happens I thought it would simply be a case of consuming the remaining jobs in all the queues and adding a poison pill to signal them to terminate.

The sub-processes do terminate BUT it seems control is NOT passed back to the "main" program and I can still see the main process hanging until I do a ctrl-c cancel in the command prompt.

Please help see my code and tell me where I am going wrong:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys, time, datetime, os, math, multiprocessing, time, random

TYPE_JOB_PART_1 = '1'
TYPE_JOB_PART_2 = '2'

class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, task_queue, result_queue, task_type):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.task_queue   = task_queue
        self.result_queue = result_queue
        self.task_type    = task_type

    def run(self):
        while True:
            next_task = self.task_queue.get()
            if next_task is None:
                #= Poison pill means shutdown
                print('%s: is exiting: %s ===============' % (self.name, self.task_type))
                self.task_queue.task_done()
                break

            job_response = next_task()
            self.task_queue.task_done()

            if self.task_type == TYPE_JOB_PART_1:
                self.result_queue.put(do_jobPart_2(job_response))

            elif self.task_type == TYPE_JOB_PART_2:
                self.result_queue.put(do_reporting(job_response))

        return

class Reporter(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, task_queue, result_queue, num_tasks, num_workers_jobPart1, num_workers_jobPart2, jobPart1_queue, jobPart2_queue):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.task_queue     = task_queue
        self.result_queue   = result_queue
        self.jobPart1_queue = jobPart1_queue
        self.jobPart2_queue = jobPart2_queue

        self.num_tasks = num_tasks
        self.num_workers_jobPart1 = num_workers_jobPart1
        self.num_workers_jobPart2 = num_workers_jobPart2

        self.time_start = datetime.datetime.now() #= Start the timer
        self.time_elapsed = 0
        self.time_wait_to_terminate = 3 #= Define the timeout to terminate all jobs

    def run(self):
        while True:
            next_task = self.task_queue.get()

            if next_task is None:
                #= Poison pill means shutdown
                self.task_queue.task_done()
                print('==================================================')
                print('============ END OF PROCESSING ===================')
                print('==================================================')
                break

            job_response = next_task()
            self.task_queue.task_done()

            self.result_queue.put(job_response)

            queueSize = self.result_queue.qsize()

            #= TERMINATTION time
            print("================>i:%s" % (queueSize))
            self.time_elapsed = (datetime.datetime.now() - self.time_start).total_seconds()

            if self.time_elapsed > self.time_wait_to_terminate:
                print("TIME IS UP. %s elapsed!" % self.time_wait_to_terminate)

                #= Empty the JobPart_1 queue to relieve the workers
                while not self.jobPart1_queue.empty():
                    self.jobPart1_queue.get()
                    self.jobPart1_queue.task_done()

                #= And add poison pills again
                for i in range(self.num_workers_jobPart1):
                    self.jobPart1_queue.put(None)

                #= Empty the JobPart_2 queue to relieve the workers
                while not self.jobPart2_queue.empty():
                    self.jobPart2_queue.get()
                    self.jobPart2_queue.task_done()

                #= And add poison pills again
                for i in range(self.num_workers_jobPart2):
                    self.jobPart2_queue.put(None)

                #= Empty the report queue to relieve the reporter itself
                while not self.task_queue.empty():
                    self.task_queue.get()
                    self.task_queue.task_done()

                print("TIME IS UP: workers stopped, Reporter shutting itself down....")
                break

            #= Results queue is filled up when count = num_tasks, so give Poison pill to shutdown JobPart_2 workers
            if queueSize == self.num_tasks:
                for i in range(self.num_workers_jobPart2):
                    self.jobPart2_queue.put(None)

                print("JobPart_2 workers will be poisoned")

        return

class do_reporting(object):
    def __init__(self, info):
        self.info = info

    def __call__(self):
        try:
            print("%s:do_reporting - is RUNNING " % (self.info['jobPart1_results']['i']))
            randtime = 0.5 * random.random()
            time.sleep(randtime)

            print( 'jobPart1_time:%s, jobPart2_time:%s, report_time;%s' % ( self.info["jobPart1_results"]["jobPart1_time"], self.info["jobPart2_time"], randtime ) )

            return {'results':self.info,'report_time':randtime}

        except:
            print("error:do_reporting")

class do_jobPart_1(object):
    def __init__(self, i, t0):
        self.t0 = t0
        self.i = i

    def __call__(self):
        try:
            print("%s:do_jobPart_1 - is RUNNING " % self.i)
            randtime = 0.5 * random.random()
            time.sleep(randtime)
            time_elapsed = (datetime.datetime.now() - self.t0).total_seconds()

            return {'i':self.i, 't0':self.t0, 'time_elapsed_job1':time_elapsed, 'jobPart1_time':randtime}

        except:
            print("error:do_jobPart_1")

class do_jobPart_2(object):
    def __init__(self, info):
        self.info = info

    def __call__(self):
        try:
            print("%s:do_jobPart_2 - is RUNNING " % (self.info['i']))
            randtime = 0.5 * random.random()
            time.sleep(randtime)

            return {"jobPart1_results":self.info,'jobPart2_time':randtime}

        except:
            print("error:do_jobPart_2")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('==================================================')
    print('============ START PROCESSING ====================')
    print('==================================================')

    #===============================================
    #= Establish communication queues
    q_jobPart_1 = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
    q_jobPart_2 = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
    q_reportTasks = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
    q_results = multiprocessing.Queue()

    #===============================================
    #= Start workersReporter !!! Should always be just 1 worker !!!
    numJobs = 90
    numWorkers_jobPart1 = 2
    numWorkers_jobPart2 = 2

    workersJobPart_1  = [ Worker(q_jobPart_1, q_jobPart_2,   TYPE_JOB_PART_1) for i in range(numWorkers_jobPart1) ]
    workersJobPart_2  = [ Worker(q_jobPart_2, q_reportTasks, TYPE_JOB_PART_2) for i in range(numWorkers_jobPart2) ]

    workerJobReporter = Reporter(q_reportTasks, q_results, numJobs, numWorkers_jobPart1, numWorkers_jobPart2, q_jobPart_1, q_jobPart_2)

    #===============================================
    #= Start the workers
    print("Main PID:%s" % os.getpid())

    for w in workersJobPart_1:
        w.start()
        print("JobPart_1 PID=%s" % w.pid)

    for w in workersJobPart_2:
        w.start()
        print("JobPart_2 PID=%s" % w.pid)

    workerJobReporter.start()
    print("JobReporter PID=%s" % workerJobReporter.pid)

    #= Start the timer and add tasks to the queues
    time_start = datetime.datetime.now()

    for i in range(numJobs):
        q_jobPart_1.put(do_jobPart_1(i, time_start))

    #= Add poison pill for each jobPart_1 workers
    for i in range(numWorkers_jobPart1):
        q_jobPart_1.put(None)

    q_jobPart_1.join()
    print("JobPart_1 workers terminated")

    q_jobPart_2.join()
    print("JobPart_2 workers terminated")

    q_reportTasks.put(None)
    q_reportTasks.join()
    workerJobReporter.terminate()

    print("Reporter terminated")
    print("FINISHED")
```

Comment: I see 2 places where you can hang: sleep() and join(). So, if you are sleeping, you can't process message from the queue. Try: a) to make join() with timeout  b) to make lesser sleep time c) to set breakpoint on line which will be reached in termination 100% and to trace from there. Also set breakpoints on lines where do you expect to be on termination but you are not sure are they reaching. If you have not debugger, try `pdb.set_trace()`

Comment: Also I'm not sure but IMHO you may have race-conditions. Your code is not really asynchronous: main communicate with slave jobs sequentially: your report job can be frozen in `get()` of queue: reporting jobs can quit and main will wait on `join()` of report job forever. Try `get()` with timeout, you should not be blocked anywhere, only to save CPU time with some reasonable timeout.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments. I just tried swapping the sequence of the join()'s on the "q_jobPart_1.join()" and "q_jobPart_2.join()" and suddenly the main process terminates naturally! But, now if I remove the terminate event and wait for all the jobs to be done normally, the main process hangs!

Comment: This mean, that you have loose of message. Something like dead-lock. For example, job is finished, you send it message and wait for response - it never happens. I usually do blocking calls very rear: better (instead of blocking) is to call method with timeout but in loop.